# Block user ip registration using mysql, php and html

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how is it possible to block a list of given ips from a mysql database table of ips.
For example i have a registration form and if the user has a different ip than the one from the mysql dbs he should see the form else he should see a message on that page "You are not allowed to use VPN/Proxy ips on this website".
First how do i create the mysql table and column, what properties do i need to add, so i can import the ips from a csv file.

```
MYSQL

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'blocked_ips'.......
```

and don't know how exactly to continue. Tried adding a column in phpmyadmin with VARCHAR(15) and after tried importing the csv file of ips, but it doesn't work, it only imports 2 rows and has only 00 containing in the 2 rows

```
<?php
//check for user ip
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
compare the ip got from the user with the mysql table column with ips
if the $ip matches with one from the table echo a message on the same page, (no pop-up).
 else {
 will echo the form below
 ?>

 <DOCTYPE html!>
 <head>
  <title> Registration</title>
   meta
   meta
 </head>
 <body>
  <table class="colortext" width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="20" width="70%">{advertiser_msg:8921}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>{advertiser_msg:1092} <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
    <td>{USERFIELD}<span id="fg" style="display: none;white-space: nowrap;"></td>
   </tr>
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am a noob in this please help.

Comment: mysql is just a database system. You need to do it in PHP. Mysql just record entry of IP, Nothing else

Comment: in the mysql database table i am storing the blocked ips that i want to compare with the user ip in order to block him. So i need to know how do i create the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_select_db("your database name")   or die(mysql_error()); 
 # Full Text Attempt
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `IP` FROM `your table` WHERE `IP` = '$ip'");
        or
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `IP` FROM `database` WHERE `IP` LIKE '%$ip%'");
        //chk for banned ip ipaddress

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
            echo "<p> You are not allowed to register with proxy VPN </p>";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: instead of the redirecting 'header("Location: http://yoursite.com/banned.php");' how do i print the error on the same page?

Comment: @adrian Yeah you can print any custom error message ..I have given a general prototype.. Did it worked??

Comment: @Valibs_Cool I am confident it will work, but my question is, how do i print the error on same page? <php print ....

Comment: @Adrian - MAke a html div and keep it displayed none and make it visible with the error ..wht you want show in the error ??

Comment: @ Valibs_Cool I want to show 'You are not allowed to register with proxy VPN'. Could you please re-edit the code. And also tell me how do i create the table so i can upload from csv format the ips?

Comment: @Adrian -- I have given you d whole code for first question. Also gave you an idea to show the error message . Do the needful for this questin and do post your second question with all the details and snippets if poss..Wil surely try to solve ..

Comment: @Valibs_Cool Please read the first part of the question. My Qestion has 2 parts, the MYSQL and the PHP. PHP is done, MYSQL is prob now.

Comment: I have updated my answer with error message .. Yeah i got it ..Let me take a look

Comment: @Vaivs_Cool managed to do the table and importing stuff with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'table_name' (ID int NOT_NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; IP varchar (255) and added some values in the table and exported the table, after i re-imported with the new values and worked importing every ip. Now the problem is, SELECT `IP` FROM `database` WHERE `IP` = '$ip'", please explain me this syntax, from what i undestood, database should be replaced with the database name but don't understand what SELECT IP and WHERE IP represents, table or column?

Comment: It works on detecting it and echo's the message along with the website form, but now i am thinking it was better on redirecting it because in this form it makes the writing ugly and it doesn't hide it. I tried adding instead of  echo "<p> You are not allowed to register with proxy VPN </p>"; like you pointed me for the first time header('location: http://www.google.com'); but it doesn't redirect the user.

Comment: did u try as i told header('location: google.com'); and then add exit();

Comment: Hope this solves your error ..Thankq fr upvote and accpeting answer.. cheers